# Service as a Model in MVC

Tags: php, mvc

I have a PHP MVC application and a file table. I need to implement the functionality: mark all as read. The best solution for the code I found so far was to put the actual implementation in a Model/Service/FileService.php

The problem is the class FileService will get bloated really fast with different functionality.

What would be a good solution to avoid bloated Services. Should I created different Services for each action?

Comment: It shouldn't be a concern imo, how much functionality a code file contains as long as the functionality belongs there. You could eventually split it up into more categories of functionality. For example "permissions", "I/O", "attributes" can all be categories.

Answer (score 2):

Start by using your FileService class. Once your service gets to bloated, extract classes from FileService and call these from FileService methods.

So, if you now have `FileService->writeFile()` with the concrete implementation, your future implementation may contain:

```
function writeFile() {
    new FileWriteService()->doStuff();
}
```

So, you can still put all file functions in one class while refactoring and grouping the concrete implementations.